# Garbage collection in Blender leaks memory

Tags: python, scripting, memory-management

I'm working on an iterative process for optimizing the placement of some objects. This iterative process seems to leak the memory (I use numpy matrices). I do destruct the lists and matrices after each iteration but seems not really helping. I've enabled GC collector and still, I have the problem. When I reload Blender the saved files take less memory, and the memory is totally freed. Can we get access to what is going on reloading Blender? I've already found some solutions but none worked with me.

Comment: Can you construct a minimal working example to reproduce the problem?

Comment: It's an iterative process (using self-learning techniques), the algorithms try to find the best location of objects according to the existing ones. Many trials (moving object) and trying to place it in its final location. The process assumes locations and moves the object to the intended location, if it didn't work due to overlapping constraints or location constraints it will try to find another better location.. and so on. For each object about 10,000 trials used (as much as the problem complexity requires).

Comment: Indeed it seems to me when moving the meshes in Blender and applying transformation processes such as rotation, scaling and location the older mesh is not destructed from the memory or it makes a copy of it and applies the changes to the copy. The former locations could be kept in memory.

Comment: Is there a way to clear the history of changes in Blender? I didn't find it in API so far ..